How to drag and drop Outlook mail attachments to Windows Forms application in .NET 6?
I have a Windows Forms application using .NET 6 and use "the new Outlook for Windows"
You have Microsoft Outlook Version 1.2024.1009.100 (Production).

Client Version is 20241018004.16.

WebView2 Version is 130.0.2849.52.

When I receive a mail with an attachment, I want to drag this attachment directly into my Windows Forms app for further processing.
For now, I tried saving the attachment as a file using the following code:
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }

    private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] formatStrings = e.Data.GetFormats(autoConvert: true);

        foreach (string formatString in formatStrings)
        {
            object dataObject = e.Data.GetData(formatString, autoConvert: true);

            if (dataObject is null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"{formatString} is null.");
            }
            else
            {
                MemoryStream memoryStream = (MemoryStream)dataObject;
                string fileName = string.Join("_", formatString.Split(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()));
                string tempPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\temp", fileName);

                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(tempPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    memoryStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }
                Debug.WriteLine($"Saved file {tempPath}");
            }
        }
    }
}

However, the actual attachment is not saved and I have no idea how to proceed/what methods to call to get the actual data of the attachment. I drag a 10MB png image on the form and the following files are saved:

The output of the program is:
Saved file C:\temp\DragContext
Saved file C:\temp\DragImageBits
Saved file C:\temp\chromium_x-renderer-taint
FileDrop is null.
FileNameW is null.
FileName is null.
Saved file C:\temp\FileGroupDescriptorW
FileContents is null.
Saved file C:\temp\Chromium Web Custom MIME Data Format

What I would expect is a file getting saved of 10MB size, since the attachment I used for testing is that big. The DragImageBits file also seems to have the same size regardless of what attachment I use for testing. I would also expect the FileName or FileNameW to contain the name of the attachment and FileContents to contain the file as a byte array/memory stream or similar.
Many solutions I found online use the GetData method and FileContents to get the attachment data and save the file, but in my application, GetData simply returns null. Has something changed with the new Outlook version? Is some manual work required, using COM objects, OleConverters, IntPtr or something? I am unfortunately hardly familiar with these topics and would appreciate some hints.

A short googling implies that dragdrop isn't implemented yet in new outlook (there might be a newer new outlook that invalidates this comment). When it is you presumably would only get a link to download the actual attachment from (you are looking at a webpage so the attachment data isn't on your system yet) . Means you still need to authenticate properly then.

Hm, dragging from Outlook into the Windows explorer works, though. I thought maybe the same magic that is used there can somehow also be implemented here.

Since you get a non-null FileGroupDescriptorW, FileContents is always null. IIRC, you should cast [IDataObject].GetData([Format], true) to a MemoryStream. The first 4 bytes represent the number of files. The pointers to the files are indexed, in the form of a FILEDESCRIPTORW struct, so you call Marshal.PtrToStructure<FILEDESCRIPTORW>([Offset]); to get the structs, the cFileName member is the name of the file. To get the file data, you initialize a FORMATETC struct, where cfFormat should be   (short)DataFormats.GetFormat("FileContents").Id, dwAspect is set to [Content] [...]

and tymed to ISTREAM | HGLOBAL. I don't remember the exact names, but these are all listed in System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes. Then initialize a STGMEDIUM struct, cast the IDataObject to [ComTypes].IDataObject), and call its GetData() method (e.g., [COM IDataObject].GetData(ref [FORMATETC], out [STGMEDIUM]). After that, check the STGMEDIUM's tymed member to see whether you got the data as a HGlobal or IStream reference (most probably the latter). Get the IStream with ([ComTypes].IStream)Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown([STGMEDIUM].unionmember) (well, probably :)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78935262/14171304
